# Storing multiple independent trees in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, tree, cypher

I want to store multiple independent trees(there is no relation between those trees). I think to generate and assign a unique label to every independent tree. Then every query will have a filter using those labels. So if there are 10,000 trees, I would have to generate 10,000 different labels. Is there a better solution like a multi-graph or something else available?

Comment: Labels are for nodes, not trees. Are you asking about using labeling all the tree nodes, or just the root node, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using one label, say `:Root`, for all of your trees and a `root_id` property that contains the tree's unique identifier.

You can [create a unique constraint](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/constraints/#administration-constraints-unique-nodes) on `root_id` to ensure that no two trees have the same ID. The unique constraint has the side effect of creating an index on the property so accessing the `:Root` nodes by `root_id` will be very fast.

Comment: I want to store only BOM trees in neo4j. Suppose there are 10^5 BOM trees where every tree has 10^5 nodes in it, so in total there are 10^10 nodes.

Case 1: Assign a unique label to every tree and my query would be:
"MATCH(n : label1 { nodeId: 100} ) return n"
"MATCH(n : label2 { nodeId: 100} ) return n"

Case 2: Assign a common label to every node and add a property tree id. Then the query would be:
"MATCH(n : bomNode { nodeId: 100, tree: 1 } ) return n"
"MATCH(n : bomNode { nodeId: 100, tree: 2 } ) return n"

Which one is better in terms of time complexity and why?

Comment: I would load a representative subset each way and then use EXPLAIN and/or PROFILE to see which is more efficient. My guess is that the single label with an indexed property will be more efficient but the query planner will let you know for certain.